# Downloading files redirects to an Error Page or Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server, filenotfoundexception, system.io.file

Downloading files redirects to an Error Page or Server Error for old files but still there in the database, but newly uploaded files is accessible. Like I upload new files today, I can still download it but my uploaded files yesterday automatically redirect to Error Page which says,
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code and System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file.

```
if (doc != null)
                {
                    string uploadFolder = Server.MapPath("~/" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"]);
                    string path = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, doc.file_path);
                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path); //error occurred here
                    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, doc.file_name);
                }
            }

the error occurred in declaring fileBytes. How to fix this?
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self containing. System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path) Couldn't find file.

Why?

1. The file is not there, where should be
2. The file is there where should be, but the path is bad, where you search.
3. The file is there, the path is good, but the permissions for file are not enough.
   etc...

You have to check and fix what cause this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found where is the problem. the file is not saved in the local everytime I pulled changes from the repository. I am new in this field and do you have any suggestions how can I keep the downloaded files so that I can access it anytime and anyday? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what is your real issue. Perhaps you just set up your csproj correctly to contains every files what will need in runtime.